# Macbook Pro Hard Reset? ... Can't install OS X

Tags: macbook-pro

Was given a 2009 Macbook Pro after original owner attempted to hard reset. Reinstall of OS X unsuccessful from OS X Utilities. I get as far as agreeing to terms, and signing in to App Store with my Apple ID, and then get this message:  "This item is temporarily unavailable.  Try again later."  I start school tomorrow and I am royally screwed if I can't figure this out. All data is clearly erased, as well as all Apps. Any info pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try burning a CD/Network boot to install the version of OS that is supported by 2009 MBP?

looks like both Mavericks and Mountain Lion are supported depending on the version of 2009.

Comment: see solution here - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6455578?tstart=0

Comment: @Sairam MBP 2009 max supported OS is 10.11.6.  It is possible to make a bootable USB with the Install OSX.app file, but he'll have to find an account which has previously downloaded El Capitan as Apple removes older OSes from the app store.

Comment: Booting/Creating from an external harddrive could be a possibility too.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add this as a viable alternative for "if ya just gotta have it right now"

Take it to an Apple Store - they'll do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that Sairam just [linked](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6455578?tstart=0) to is this (so we have the solution **here,** as preferred)

The reason you get this message is *your* AppleID is not associated with an o/s installation. If you use someone elses AppleID. You'll get all *their* apps.

1. In the 4 choices you get click "GET HELP ONLINE"
2. This opens Safari.
3. Click icloud and sign in with your AppleID.

Comment: I've been watching this question since I saw Sairam's comment & would love to know if this works even if you don't have that particular OS in your purchase history. It seems to have a lot going for it as an answer, but I just have a feeling it may fall down at that point, for a new user.

Comment: Yah, it was news to me. I would think at-least the OS the Mac came with. But now that macOS is free...

Answer (score 0):

Login with the original owners Apple ID - old copies of OS X are not available unless your Apple ID has a license for it.

Comment: The OS will then still belong to the old owner. Might be quick, but not a good long-term solution.

Comment: I read your comment wrong at first - maybe the OS would technically belong to the original owner (I have no idea if that's actually true) but it doesn't affect any part of the OS or support agreements. AFAIK Apple does not grant access to old OS's through Apple ID at all if you haven't downloaded it previously. If you were to take it into an Apple Store they would just install it off of an old thumb drive or sign in with the stores Apple ID in Internet Recovery.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a bootable USB with the Install OSX.app file, but you  will need to use an account which has previously downloaded El Capitan; Apple removes older OSes from the app store.

Obviously you will need access to a Mac to download the file, format a USB drive as GUID/HFS, then [read here on your options by OS version](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

An example using freshly formatted USB drive 'MyVolume':

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app
```

Then hold option when rebooting, pick USB drive MyVolume, and follow the install prompts.